# Request to api works fine in component but not when using provider with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-data-table-component

When making a request to my API from a component and using react-data-table-component everything works perfectly but if I try to make the request from my Product Provider the pagination is incorrect and no longer works as expected.

With this code I make the request, datatable and pagination from my component working perfectly:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback, useMemo } from "react";
import axiosClient from "../config/axiosClient";
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component-with-filter'
import { CSVLink } from "react-csv"
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import useProducts from "../hooks/useProducts";

const removeItem = (array, item) => {
  const newArray = array.slice();
  newArray.splice(newArray.findIndex(a => a === item), 1);

  return newArray;
};

const ProductsTest = () => {
  

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [totalRows, setTotalRows] = useState(0);
  const [perPage, setPerPage] = useState(10);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [searchBox, setSearchBox] = useState('')

  
  const STRING_TRADUCTIONS = { "KILOGRAM" : "KILOGRAMOS", "GRAMS" : "GRAMOS", "BOX" : "CAJA", "PACKAGE" : "PAQUETE", "BOTTLE" : "BOTE", "PIECES" : "PIEZAS", "BAG" : "BOLSA", "LITER" : "LITRO" }

  const fetchUsers = async (page, limit = perPage, search = searchBox) => {
    setLoading(true)
    const dataOnLs = localStorage.getItem('cmtjs')

    const config = {
      headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          apiKey: dataOnLs
      } ,
      params: {
          limit,
          page, 
          search
        }            
  }
    const response = await axiosClient(`/products`, config)
    const data = response.data.products.docs.map( doc => (
      {
          _id: doc._id,
          idProduct: doc.idProduct,
          barCode: doc.barCode,
          name: doc.name,
          presentation: STRING_TRADUCTIONS[doc.presentation],
          salePrice: doc.salePrice,
          purchasePrice: doc.purchasePrice,
          stock: doc.stock,
          user: doc.user.username,
          category: doc.category.name,
          provider: doc.provider.name
      }
  ))
      setData(data);
      setTotalRows(response.data.products.totalDocs);
      setLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers(1)
  }, []);

  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        name: "ID",
        selector: "idProduct",
        sortable: true
      },
      {
        name: "Código de Barras",
        selector: "barCode",
        sortable: true
      },
      {
        name: "Nombre",
        selector: "name",
        sortable: true
      },
      {
        name: "Presentación",
        selector: "presentation",
        sortable: true
      },
      {
        name: "Precio",
        selector: "salePrice",
        sortable: true
      },
      {
        name: "Stock",
        selector: "stock",
        sortable: true
      },
     { cell: row => 
      <Link to={ `/dashboard/product/${row._id}`}>
        <button className='btn btn-ghost text-xs'>
            Mas
        </button>
      </Link>}
    ]
  );

  const handlePageChange = page => {
    fetchUsers(page);
    setCurrentPage(page);
  };

  const handlePerRowsChange = async (newPerPage, page) => {
    fetchUsers(page, newPerPage);
    setPerPage(newPerPage);
  }

  const headers = [
    { label: "ID", key: "idProduct" },
    { label: "Código de Barras", key: "barCode" },
    { label: "Nombre", key: "name" },
    { label: "Presentación", key: "presentation" },
    { label: "Precio Venta", key: "salePrice" },
    { label: "Precio Compra", key: "purchasePrice" },
    { label: "Stock", key: "stock" },
    { label: "Creador", key: "user" },
    { label: "Categoría", key: "category" },
    { label: "Proveedor", key: "provider" }
  ]

  const paginationComponentOptions = {
    rowsPerPageText: 'Mostrar',
    rangeSeparatorText: 'de',
    selectAllRowsItem: true,
    selectAllRowsItemText: 'Todos',
};

const clear = () => { 
  setPerPage(10)
  setSearchBox('')
  fetchUsers(1, 10, '')
}

  return (

    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e)=> setSearchBox(e.target.value)}/>
      <button onClick={ ()=> fetchUsers()}>Buscar</button>

      <CSVLink data={data} headers={headers} filename={"productos.cdtmx.csv"} className="cursor-pointer">
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
      </CSVLink>      
      <DataTable
        columns={columns}
        data={data}
        progressPending={loading}
        pagination
        paginationServer
        paginationTotalRows={totalRows}
        paginationDefaultPage={currentPage}
        onChangeRowsPerPage={handlePerRowsChange}
        onChangePage={handlePageChange}
        selectableRows
        //onSelectedRowsChange={({ selectedRows }) => console.log(selectedRows)}
        paginationComponentOptions={paginationComponentOptions}
        noDataComponent="No hay resultados"
      />
      {
        searchBox && searchBox !== ''  &&  <button onClick={ () => clear() }>Limpiar</button>
      }
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

But I have my product provider where I make a get request to all my products, avoiding making the requests from my component and having the data globally, but if I use "getProducts" from my provider, the first view of the datatable is correct however , when clicking on a page or next, the pager advances but the data displayed does not, for example: it shows me the first 10 records but I ask for the next 10 and the pager advances correctly but the data is still the first 10 records, No I know how to use my provider and make the pager show the following data depending on what the user needs.

This is the code of my provider to obtain the product data

```
    const getProducts = async(page, limit, search) => { 
       
        const dataOnLs = localStorage.getItem('cmtjs')

        const config = {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                apiKey: dataOnLs
            } ,
            params: {
                page,
                limit,
                search
              }            
        }
        try {
            const { data } = await axiosClient(`/products`, config)
            setProducts(data)
        } catch (error) {
```

So in my component I call "getProducts" from my provider to have the products data in "products" using the useEffect hook

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getProducts()
    setData(products.products?.docs)
    setTotalRows(products.products?.totalDocs)
    setLoading(false)
  }, []);
```

In my paginator to obtain the following 10 product records, I click and the text changes that indicates which page is being shown, but the data remains the same as the first page

```
  const handlePageChange = page => {
    getProducts(page); // it does not show the next 10 records as it happened in the fetch of my component
    setCurrentPage(page); // OK
  };
```

[image: pagination error]

In the same way, my browser no longer works using it in this way, I only changed the function to call my provider now, but it does not work

```
      <input type="text" onChange={(e)=> setSearchBox(e.target.value)}/>
      <button onClick={ ()=> getProducts()}>Buscar</button>
```

I would like to know if you can help me to make my datatable and browser work using my provider. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    getProducts()
    setData(products.products?.docs)
    setTotalRows(products.products?.totalDocs)
    setLoading(false)
  }, []);
```

You are calling `getProducts()`, which is asynchronous. Then you try `setData(products...)`, but the asynchronous call did not finish yet, so `products` was not updated yet. When eventually the asynchronous code terminates, the `useEffect` statement is not triggered again, because the dependency array states that the effect is only executed when the component mounts.

Split up your effect in two parts instead, so the second effect gets triggered when new `products` are available:

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    getProducts()
  }, []);

 useEffect(() => {
    setData(products.products?.docs)
    setTotalRows(products.products?.totalDocs)
    setLoading(false)
  }, [products]);
```

Comment: Thanks friend, that works for paging but do you know why my search engine still doesn't work? it works fine with the fetch from the component but not using my provider

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing the whole code. In the code where you get your products from the provider, are you sure you run the useEffect hook, that calls setData, setTotalRows etc.? If this effect is not active, you would have to call setData, setTotalRows, setLoading in your provider manually after fetching the products.

Comment: Thanks for your help I was able to achieve it by indicating getProducts(1, perPage, searchBox) and with that the search and pagination goes perfectly. Thanks!